# Create index if it does not exist

Tags: postgresql, index, functions, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

I am working on a function that allows me to add an index if it does not exist. I am running into the problem that I cannot get a list of indexes to compare to. Any thoughts?

This is a similar issue to the column creation one that is solved with this code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12603892/368511

Comment: you can try: SELECT * from pg_indexes where schemaname = '[schemaname]' and indexname = '[indexname]'. Replace [schemaname] and [indexname] with proper values. Ref: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/view-pg-indexes.html

Comment: Postgres 9.5+: `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS…`

Answer (score 132, accepted):

#### Index names in PostgreSQL

- Index names are unique across a single database schema.
- Index names cannot be the same as any other index, (foreign) table, (materialized) view, sequence or user-defined composite type in the same schema.
- Two tables in the same schema cannot have an index of the same name. (Follows logically.)

If you do not care about the name of the index, have Postgres auto-name it:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl1 (col1);
```

is (almost) the same as:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl1_col1_idx ON tbl1 USING btree (col1);
```

Except that Postgres will avoid a naming collisions and automatically pick the next free name:

```
tbl1_col1_idx 
tbl1_col1_idx2
tbl1_col1_idx3
...
```

Just try it. But, obviously, you would *not* want to create multiple redundant indexes. So it wouldn't be a good idea to just blindly create a new one.

### Test for existence

#### Postgres 9.5 or newer

Now available:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ...
```

Also works for `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS`.

However, [the manual warns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html):

> Note that there is no guarantee that the existing index is anything
> like the one that would have been created.

It's a plain check for the object name. (Applies to variants for older versions below, too.)
To find existing indexes on the same table for the same column(s):

```
SELECT pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid)
FROM   pg_index
WHERE  indrelid = 'public.big'::regclass
AND   (indkey::int2[])[:] = ARRAY (
   SELECT attnum
   FROM   unnest('{usr_id, created_at}'::text[]) WITH ORDINALITY i(attname, ord)
   JOIN  (
      SELECT attname, attnum
      FROM   pg_attribute
      WHERE  attrelid = 'public.big'::regclass
      ) a USING (attname)
   ORDER BY ord
   );
```

Restrictions:

- Only works for columns, not other index expressions.
- Also reports partial indexes (with `WHERE` clause) and covering indexes (with `INCLUDE` clause).
- Reports any type of index, not just B-tree indexes.

Study the results (if any) before proceeding, or refine the query to your needs ...

Further reading:

- [Find tables with multiple indexes on same column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204706/find-tables-with-multiple-indexes-on-same-column/204733#204733)
- [Normalize array subscripts for 1-dimensional array so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44448230/939860)

#### Postgres 9.4

You can use the new function `to_regclass()` to check without throwing an exception:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
   IF to_regclass('myschema.mytable_mycolumn_idx') IS NULL THEN
      CREATE INDEX mytable_mycolumn_idx ON myschema.mytable (mycolumn);
   END IF;

END
$$;
```

Returns NULL if an index (or another object) of that name does not exist. See:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089729/939860)

This doesn't work for `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`, since that variant cannot be wrapped in an outer transaction. See [comment by @Gregory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35616/create-index-if-it-does-not-exist/35626?noredirect=1#comment131197_35626) below.

#### Postgres 9.3 or older

Cast the schema-qualified name to [`regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html):

```
SELECT 'myschema.myname'::regclass;
```

If it throws an exception, the name is free.
Or, to test the same without throwing an exception, use a [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) statement:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT
      FROM   pg_class c
      JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
      WHERE  c.relname = 'mytable_mycolumn_idx'
      AND    n.nspname = 'myschema'
   ) THEN
    
        CREATE INDEX mytable_mycolumn_idx ON myschema.mytable (mycolumn);
    END IF;
END
$$;
```

The [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) statement was introduced with Postgres 9.0. In earlier versions you have to create a [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) to do the same.
Details about [`pg_class` in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html).
Basics about [indexes in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html).

Comment: While being a great answer, do note that you can't add indexes `CONCURRENTLY` this way.  You'll get `ERROR: CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string`.

Comment: @gregoltsov: This was addressed in later updates of the answer.

Answer (score 13):

It will be available in 9.5.
Here is actual git commit https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/08309aaf74ee879699165ec8a2d53e56f2d2e947

Discussion on pg hackers http://postgresql.nabble.com/CREATE-IF-NOT-EXISTS-INDEX-td5821173.html

Comment: from the documentation, it's 9.6 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createindex.html, not the 9.5 as its mark as unsupported version